# What is the common name for a ventilated driver seat providing a cool-or-warm air draft?

Tags: hvac, air

I recently drove a car with the nicest feature I've seen in a car in recent memory: a gentle air draft from micro holes is directed at the back of the driver.

If, like me, you've had your share of long (or short) drives after which your shirt was damp from sweat (cooler inside/outside temperatures and a ventilated seat cushion notwithstanding), you'll appreciate the significance of this feature.

What is this feature called, or otherwise how can I identify the brands/models that offer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cadillac calls them ["Heated and Ventilated Seats"](https://www.cadillac.com/support/quick-start-guides/lyriq/heated-ventilated-controls) ... I'm sure other manufacturers call them something similar, but this should allow you to find the features.

Comment: Thanks. Now a quick search leads to a summary list: https://www.cars.com/articles/which-cars-have-cooled-seats-438946/ .
The next question is to determine the models that also provide the vanishing feature (but compelling to me) of manual transmission.